# Error with Neo4j Import Tool

Tags: java, csv, import, neo4j

I'm trying to import data from CSVs using the import tool with 2.2.0. 
I keep running into this error from the messages.log file:

```
2015-02-10 16:14:44.792+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Import starting
2015-02-10 16:14:45.032+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Creating new db @ C:\path\to\file\Neo4j\test.graphdb\neostore
2015-02-10 16:14:47.727+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Error during import Missing header of type START_ID
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing header of type START_ID
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.StageExecution.stillExecuting(StageExecution.java:61)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.anyStillExecuting(ExecutionSupervisor.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.finishAwareSleep(ExecutionSupervisor.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.supervise(ExecutionSupervisor.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.executeStages(ParallelBatchImporter.java:263)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:153)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:213)
Caused by: org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.MissingHeaderException: Missing header of type START_ID
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.DataFactories$AbstractDefaultFileHeaderParser.validateHeader(DataFactories.java:366)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.DataFactories$AbstractDefaultFileHeaderParser.create(DataFactories.java:315)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputGroupsDeserializer.createNestedIterator(InputGroupsDeserializer.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputGroupsDeserializer.createNestedIterator(InputGroupsDeserializer.java:35)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.NestingIterator.fetchNextOrNull(NestingIterator.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.IteratorBatcherStep.nextOrNull(IteratorBatcherStep.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep.process(ProducerStep.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep$1.run(ProducerStep.java:54)
```

the first five lines of the three files that I'm trying to import look like this: 
loctest.csv

```
LOCATION:ID;LOC_TYPE:int;NUM_MILE:int;STREET_PRE;STREETNAME;STREETTYPE;STREETSUF;APT_NO;X_STREET;:LABEL
895WTWELFTHST;1;895;W;TWELFTH;ST;;107;;LOCATION
145SFRANKLINST;1;145;S;FRANKLIN;ST;;;;LOCATION
11735GLACIERHWY;1;11735;;GLACIER;HWY;;;;LOCATION
MENDENHALL LOOPUNIVERSITY DRRDUNIVERSITY DR;2;;;MENDENHALL LOOPUNIVERSITY DR;RD;;;UNIVERSITY DR;LOCATION
```

zip5.csv

```
ZIP5:ID;ZIP4;:LABEL
99801;;ZIP5
99824;;ZIP5
99821;;ZIP5
99803;;ZIP5
```

locziptest.csv

```
:START_ID;CITY;:END_ID;:TYPE
895WTWELFTHST;JUNEAU;99801;CITY
145SFRANKLINST;JUNEAU;99801;CITY
11735GLACIERHWY;JUNEAU;99801;CITY
MENDENHALL LOOPUNIVERSITY DRRDUNIVERSITY DR;JUNEAU;99801;CITY
```

the offending file seems to be the relationships file (locziptest.csv), but the header looks like it is configured correctly. is the issue with the lookup string in the ID field? does it need to be entirely numeric?

Comment: the formatting looks like you're having a space character as first character in the header lines - please check this. If this isn't the problem, paste your exact command line for neo4j-import.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster I'm not sure why but SO's formatting is adding that space, my files don't have it. The command I'm running is `bin\Neo4jImport.bat --into C:\Users\path\to\db --nodes loctest.csv --nodes zip5.csv --relationships locziptest.csv`

Comment: not sure, but try to add `--id-type STRING`.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster it's still throwing the same error: `Missing header of type START_ID`. Is it just not reading the relationships file?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster I tried to run it with an empty relationships file that only had a header in it and still am getting that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave this a try and imported your sample data using the arguments:

`--into graph.db
--nodes loctest.csv
--nodes zip5.csv
--relationships locziptest.csv
--delimiter ;
--array-delimiter "|"`

and please don't quote the semicolons in the CSV files. I think the discussion was around quotation of the semicolon in the command prompt, which doesn't need to be quoted either

Comment: I'm not sure if it's performing correctly. The import seems to be processing the data now, thanks to your suggestions, but it just shows "Nodes" at the prompt. for reference, my files are roughly 100,000 lines each. Any idea how long it _should_ take?

Comment: for what it's worth - it does work, I made smaller files just as a test and everything performed correctly. It just takes a while with the bigger files.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be terribly over optimistics to expect a couple of hundred thousand up to 1M entities (node or relationship) added per second or so.

Answer (score 1):

Your csv uses semicolon as field separator. `neo4j-import` defaults to comma, so amend to your `neo4j-import` call:

```
--delimiter ";" --array-delimiter ","
```

The array-delimiter setting is necessary since this one defaults to semicolon and both cannot be the same.

Comment: now I'm getting: 
`Nodes
Import error: Invalid digit character -16 '?' where the original char was ' '`

Comment: your comment seems garbled. I tried the above using Linux, maybe windows command line needs some quoting for the semicolon.

Comment: I am using windows. You're saying that in the nodes CSVs I need to add quotes around the semicolon?

Comment: yes, my gut feeling is that windows cmd line is interpreting the semicolon, here. On Linux' bash the above worked nicely, the graph gets imported without errors.

Comment: weird. now, after replacing all of the `;` with `";"` in my CSVs, I get `Import error: 'ID"'`

Comment: I guess the simplest solution is to use simple commas in your CSVs and omit '--delimiter'.

Comment: so, the header of the zip5.csv looks like this `ZIP5:ID";"ZIP4";":LABEL` instead of this `ZIP5:ID;ZIP4;:LABEL`

Comment: In the headers of the two node CSVs, I removed the 'int' specifiers and swapped out the ; delimiters for commas. It seems to be loading but has been processing for about 20 minutes now, Nodes pops up and that's where it hangs.

Comment: Don't quote the semicolons in the CSV files. See my other answer above.